# Congruence modulo 4 for a generating function leads to perfect squares?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics, partitions

Consider the number of integer partitions $p(n)$ of $n$ whose generating function is
$$\sum_{n\geq0}p(n)\,x^n=\prod_{k\geq1}\frac1{1-x^k}.$$
Also, the number of partitions into distinct parts $Q(n)$ of $n$ whose genertaing function is
$$\sum_{n\geq0}Q(n)x^n=\prod_{k\geq1}(1+x^k).$$
Expand the ratio of these two generating functions so that
$$\sum_{n\geq0}a(n)x^n=\prod_{k\geq1}\frac{1+x^k}{1-x^k}.$$

> **QUESTION.** Why is $a(n)\equiv 2\,\, (\text{mod}\, 4)$ iff $n$ is a perfect square, for $n\geq1$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$2$-adic valuations: a tale of two $q$-series](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/404664/2-adic-valuations-a-tale-of-two-q-series) A more general statement is proved there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\frac{1+x^k}{1-x^k}=(1+x^k)(1+x^k+x^{2k}+\dots)=1+2x^k+2x^{2k}+\dots$$
Multiplying all these together and looking at terms contributing to the coefficient of $x^n$, we see that the term will be contributing something divisible by $4$ unless it comes from multiplying a bunch of $1$s together with $2x^{k\cdot d}$ for $k\mid n$. This means $a(n)\equiv 2d(n)\pmod 4$, where $d(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$. Since $d(n)$ is odd iff $n$ is a square, we get the result.